# Smoothing FFT result

Tags: numpy, fourier-transform, fft

I am trying to calculate the spectrum of Bremmstrahlung, which involves calculating the Fourier transformed acceleration. I am solving a non-linear ODE to numerically calculate the acceleration in the time domain. After taking the Fourier transformation using Numpy's fft, the resultant spectrum looks highly non-smooth and "non-physical" .
I cannot paste the entire code so I am posting what I think is relevant snippet. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Note: My acceleration is a function of two variables (beta, and b, the impact parameter), and I want to plot it for the different b, and in order to factor out the beta term I am just summing over all the values of acceleration for the different beta, for a given impact parameter b.

Also my spectrum is Fourier transformed acceleration square times a constant factor (Larmor's formula)
[image]
[image]

```
'''
Fourier Transformation of the acceleration
'''
N = 2**8
sampling_frequency = 10
a_w_normalized = [[] for a in range(len(impact_parameter))]
a_w =[[] for a in range(len(impact_parameter))]
intensity_normalized = [[] for a in range(len(impact_parameter))]
acc_summed_over_velocity = []
intensity_summed_over_velocity =[]

for index,b in enumerate(impact_parameter):
    acc_sum =[0 for x in range(N)]
    intensity_sum = [0 for x in range(N)] 
    for j in range(len(velocity_z_component)):
        #window_kaiser = signal.kaiser(N, 15)
        #window_hann = signal.hann(N,sym=True)
        window =1
        fft_input = acc_normalized[index][j]*window
        ft_acc_normalized = np.abs(np.fft.fft(fft_input,norm=None))

        acc_sum =np.add(ft_acc_normalized,acc_sum )
        intensity_list = [power_spectrum_factor * (a ** 2) for a in ft_acc_normalized]
        intensity_sum = np.add(intensity_list,intensity_sum)
        intensity_normalized[index].append(intensity_list)
        a_w_normalized[index].append(ft_acc_normalized)
    acc_summed_over_velocity.append(acc_sum)
    intensity_summed_over_velocity.append(intensity_sum *acceleration_factor**2)

#intensity_summed_over_velocity=  ma.masked_less_equal(intensity_summed_over_velocity,1e-5)

'''
Plotting acceleration for selected values of impact paramters in time and frequency domain
'''

if plot is True:
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    for i in range(len(impact_parameter)):
        plt.plot(t,acc_timedomain_summed_over_velocity[i], label='b={:.3f}'.format(impact_parameter[i]), )
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylabel(r'$ a(\tilde t) $', fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel(r'$ \tilde t $', fontsize=14)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
    plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
    if screening is False:
        plt.title('a(t) vs time without screening',fontsize=15)
        plt.savefig('./Plots/acc_without_screening.png')
    else:
        plt.title('a(t) vs time with screening',fontsize=15)
        plt.savefig('./Plots/acc_with_screening.png')

    '''
    Fourier transformed intensity for different impact paramater
    '''

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    freq_normalized = np.fft.fftfreq(N)*(2*np.pi*sampling_frequency)
    for index,b in enumerate(plasma.impact_parameter):
        plt.plot(np.abs(freq_normalized), intensity_summed_over_velocity[index], label=r'$ \tilde b={:.2f}$'.format(b), )
    plt.xlabel(r'$ \tilde \omega $', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel(r'$ I_{\omega} $', fontsize=16)
    plt.legend(loc="lower left")
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=12)

    if screening is False:
        plt.title('Single particle spectrum without screening')
        plt.savefig('./Plots/spectrum_no_screening.png')
    else:
        plt.title('Single particle spectrum with screening')
        plt.savefig('./Plots/spectrum_debye_screening.png')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: I think there's some confusion about the order of the coefficients in the spectrum. Check np.fft.fftshift() to get your spectrum in the correct order.

Comment: @AlexE Thanks for the comment. fftshift shift the zero-frequency component to the center of the spectrum. I am not sure how that will help me in getting a smooth spectrum. I expect my Fourier transformed acceleration to rise up and then fall.

Comment: I have a hard time to follow the outline in your question but just one thing: You said the spectra are highly non-smooth, but from the images that you attached I don't see that, cause they look pretty okayish to me. At least there are no wild noisy behavior, so I'm not sure what's your purpose here.

Comment: I missed out on your use of fftfreq(). This should get you frequencies in a matching order, so you're probably fine without fftshift. Why are you abs()ing your frequencies for the plot?

Comment: @AlexE Well I have to plot the final spectrum on log-log plot so I need to take the absolute value. Anyway, since my data is real, I think all the information is contained in positive frequencies. I should have used rfft and rfftfreq to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I don't want the valleys that I am getting in the spectrum, especially for the first two values of b. The spectrum is un-physical too, i.e. we don't expect such spectra from our process.

Comment: @Prav001 I see... I can't find anything wrong with your code, but just based on my intuition specially for $b = 0.1$, in time-domain you have a really sharp and big peaks near $t = 0$, so I expect to get a peak at least in frequency domain. But, it's a Bremmstrahlung and as far as I know there should not be any sharp peak... So, are you sure the ODE that you are solving is correctly implemented and validated?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Well my advisor said that the acceleration in time domain plot looks alright so I am assuming the ODE's are solved correctly, but I have no method to verify the solution. If you know any, can you suggest one? I was thinking using a "pefect" combination of windows will get rid of the bumps but no luck in finding such windows.

Comment: @Prav001 That's not actually a bump that you could ignore it or get rid of it easily you know... That's a peak. There should be a reason behind that peak. Can you put a reference that shows your nonlinear ODE + initial or boundary conditions to solve it?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Yes, that's what I am worried, but I also don't understand why I am getting the peaks only for small b's. We don't see any such peak for b=10, and 100.
 Here is the screenshot of the relevant ODE.https://imgur.com/a/CEIZyMp
 The ODE has two parameters $\beta$ and $\tilde b$, and I am simply summing all values of $\beta$. I am then substituting the value of $\tilde z$ in my acceleration equation. The initial condition for ODE is $\frac{d\tilde z}{d\tilde t}$ = 0 for $\tilde t$=0.